# Apply function to specific rows of dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x

I have a following column in a dataframe:

```
COLUMN_NAME
1
0
1
1
65280
65376
65280
```

I want to convert 5 digit values in a column to their corresponding binary values. I know how to convert it by using `bin()` function, but i don't know how to apply it only to rows that has 5digits.

Note that the column contains only values with either 1 or 5 digits. Values with 1 digit is only 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'c':  [1,0,1,1,65280,65376,65280] }
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['c'])

// create another column 'clen' which has length of 'c'
df['clen'] = df['c'].astype(str).map(len)

//check condition and apply bin function to entire column
df.loc[df['clen']==5,'c'] = df['c'].apply(bin)
```